# Single Phase Induction Motor Wiring help

Tags: capacitor, motor, wiring, single-phase

I have purchased a Single Phase Induction Motor that runs anti-clockwise, I require it to run clockwise however I am unable to figure how to change the wiring to do this, any help would be appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhnES.jpg

Worth noting, if I fully remove the starting capacitor, the motor starts in anti-clockwise even if I give it a spin clockwise before switching it on.

[image]

Comment: When you use the CircuitLab schematic button on the editor toolbar the schematic gets saved inline in your question and is editable. No need for screengrab and upload. Post links to the images and someone will inline those for you as you don't have enough rep. I'll give you some.

Comment: Can you read any markings on the white terminal block?

Comment: The motor nameplate seems to be marked incorrectly. The V2-Z2 connection between the CW & CCW diagrams makes no sense. The existing terminal-block wiring is not constant with the nameplate. It looks like one might be a mirror image of the other. We will need to deduce the correct diagram from looking at the motor wiring. The drawing provided should help. There is an error on that. The P4 and P5 connections are interchanged.

Comment: In the diagram, there must be something other than the P5-P6 link connected to P6.

Comment: @CharlesCowie I have added a new picture to the bottom of the original link/album, unsure if that helps you?

I agree the nameplate is incorrect however I don't know how to fix it, I tried swapping the wires under Z1W1 and V1 however that did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In order to reverse a single phase motor, the main winding must be reversed with respect to the auxiliary winding and series capacitor circuit. The change is done by moving the links so that the connection one pair of wires is transferred from one of the incoming power lines to the other. A second pair of wires remains connected to the same power line as before. The nameplate shows the links moved from U!-V1 & U2-Z2 to U1-Z2 & U2-V1. The line between V2 of the left (CW) diagram and Z2 if the right (CCW) diagram is an error.

The linked terminals should have the two incoming power wires and four other wires connected to them. Otherwise, the motor can't be reversed the way the nameplate shows.