# How to wire up single phase induction motor?

Tags: wiring, induction-motor

I bought a single phase induction motor with two capacitors, but I do not know how to read the wiring diagram on this motor.

[image: wiring diagram]

[image]

Comment: It appears that the orientation of the terminals does not match the diagram on the rating plate. Can you identify where the three pairs of wires are coming from? I mean the blue & red wires in the white cable, the brown and blue wires in the black cable at the bottom left and the green and blue? wires in the black painted gray cable at the top. This question is very similar to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/365698/single-phase-induction-motor-wiring-help.

Comment: Please add a better picture: move the white cable out of the way and make sure that you include all of the spec label with the wiring connection.

Comment: Please also mark up that picture (if possible) with whatever lettering is molded into the plastic terminal block.  I can sort of see something near each terminal but my eyes can't make out what the text is.

Comment: Yeah. It looks like the letters from the diagram are molded into the white plastic of the terminal block. OP needs to annotate the photo to show which one is which. I have my guess already, but I would rather the OP just annotate the picture to make it all clear.

Comment: Notable nothing goes to the earth terminal - that needs correcting.

Comment: From the plate it look like the wires stay the same, but the jumpers change to go from CW to CCW rotation. The terminal block is labeled to match the plate wiring, but there is not enough contrast to make out the letters.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram is in two parts, the left side is the connection for clockwise rotation, the right for counterclockwise.

In both the capacitor is connected to the same terminals, V2 and Z1, presumably the left two as seen  in the photo, which is upside down relative to the diagram. The second cap isn't detailed in the diagram, presumably that's a start capacitor that is internally connected to the centrifugal start switch (the light blue colored wires that disappear into the body).

The two brass links are then to be connected horizontal or vertical to set the rotation - as photographed it's clockwise. The effect of swapping the links it to reverse the current through the auxiliary winding relative to the main winding (it doesn't matter which one is actually being reconnected).

Comment: This is my interpretation also. Sure wish the OP would annotate the picture though.